# Can We Prove These Removed Areas Are an Arc?

Tags: geometry, solution-verification, proof-writing, circles, arc-length

[I've been delving into math during my free time and came across an intriguing problem involving the perimeter of a shaded region. This particular challenge is part of a module that focuses on arc length.

Looking at the diagram, you'll notice an arc length or sector taken from the square. The solution involves calculating this arc length and subtracting it from the square's perimeter.

However, I've deviated a bit from the usual problem-solving steps. I'm attempting to rigorously prove that the four areas taken away from the square truly represent an arc. I've encountered some challenges along the way, prompting me to seek assistance in determining whether this is a provable concept.

So, **before delving into the details, can we conclusively establish, based solely on the diagram, that these removed areas are indeed an arc**?            look at the image: ][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMdUM.png)